# Persistent menu with Microsoft Botframework

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot

How to add a persistent menu to Microsoft Bot framework? I searched in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) but I do not find much information about UI components.
I want to achieve something like the persistent menu of Messenger bot

[image]

```
  <script>
    var speechOptions = {
    speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer( { subscriptionKey: '***********' } ),
    speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer(
        {
            subscriptionKey: '*************',
            gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
            voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
        })
}


        BotChat.App({

        //production evironment
        directLine: { secret: '**********************' },
        user: { id: Date.now().toString(), name: 'You'},
        bot: { id: '1234' },
        resize: 'detect',
        speechOptions: speechOptions
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
```

Comment: The Bot Framework does support the Facebook Messenger channel. Are you saying you want to recreate a Facebook Messenger feature in Web Chat? If you want to use Web Chat then you should definitely use Web Chat v4 instead of Bot Chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, it looks like you are using Web Chat v3 which is sunset and no longer supported. I would highly recommend [migrating to v4](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#migrating-from-web-chat-v3-to-v4).

There is currently an issue open in the Web Chat Repository to add a sample for a persistent menu. You can track that issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1293).

In terms of creating your own persistent menu, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709055/send-message-to-bot-on-click-of-menu-item-bot-framework/57715813#57715813) Stack Overflow question. You can add a persistent menu to the window and then dispatch actions to the Web Chat store when the user clicks the action. I imagine you could do something similar in v3 and post an activity from the `botconnection` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I will upgrade to v4. I followed the github issue. Could you please help on my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811313/how-to-get-message-back-from-adaptive-card ?