# How to get message back from Adaptive card

Tags: json, azure, botframework, adaptive-cards

I use an adaptive card that has 2 actions.

```
"actions": [

    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Cards related queries",
      "data": "Cards_intent"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Accounts related queries",
      "data": "Accounts_intent"
    }
]
```

But when the users select on action, I don't want the user to see "Accounts_intent" displayed in the chat box. Instead, I want "Accounts related queries" to be displayed

The issue:

[image]

Comment: Hey, one thing you can try is putting your `data` value as a json with keys `value` and `id`, eg:       `"data": {
        "value": "Accounts related queries",
        "id": "Accounts_intent"
      }` then both `id` and `value` will come through in your `stepContext.Result`. You can then do your logic knowing `Accounts_intent` was passed to your next step and `Accounts related queries` will be sent to the chat.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a few options

### Option #1

If you want to keep using an Adaptive Card and your only concern is what shows up in the conversation history, just change the string in the `data` property to whatever you want to be displayed.

```
{
  "type": "Action.Submit",
  "title": "Accounts related queries",
  "data": "Accounts related queries"
}
```

Your bot must know to respond to an activity with "Accounts related queries" as the text. Keep in mind that the user would also be able to type "Accounts related queries" to achieve the same result.

### Option #2

If you are using strings as your submit action data, your card must not have any input fields. This means you can use any kind of rich card instead of an Adaptive Card, or you could even use suggested actions.

If you definitely want your activity to contain different text from what the user sees in the conversation history, you will only be able to do this on channels that support it. Facebook Messenger lets you do this, but it does not support Adaptive Cards. Having one set of visible text and another set of hidden data is often called a `messageBack` card action.

### Option #3

If you don't care about the user seeing anything in the conversation history, you can either use craigbot's idea of having the submit action's data be an object instead of a string, or you can use a card action in a rich card other than an Adaptive Card.

If you'd like to learn more about Adaptive Cards and especially submit actions, please have a look at my latest blog post: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Comment: I tried with option #2 . Does Webchat and Bot Framework emulator supports this feature ?

Comment: @TSR - The Emulator actually uses Web Chat, and yes they support messageBack

Answer (score 0):

The simple one word answer is `messageBack`. You can use this in `data:{}` and mention the text that you'd like to be shown from user side in `displayText` and you'll be able to get a text back from user side when they click on any of the button.

```
"actions": [

    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Cards related queries",
      "data":{
                 "msteams":{
                       "type":"messageBack",
                       "displayText":"Cards related queries"
                   },
                   "value":"Cards_intent"
              }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Accounts related queries",
       "data":{
                 "msteams":{
                       "type":"messageBack",
                       "displayText":"Accounts relates queries"
                   },
                   "value":"Accounts_intent"
              }
    }
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).